# how to specify download filename or retrieving downloaded file in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using selenium for /NET 4.0 with C#/.

I am downloading a file by entering a date range and clicking export:

this automatically downloads a CSV into the default download location that is set on my browser:

[image]

```
public static void Downloadreport()
{
    selenium.Open("https://mlis.millenniumlabs.com/Admin/Reports/SpecimenVolume.aspx");

    //selenium.Click("link=Specimen Volume Report - Drugs");
    selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.Click("id=ctl00_cphBody_dtpFrom");
    selenium.Type("id=ctl00_cphBody_dtpFrom", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    selenium.Type("id=ctl00_cphBody_dtpTo", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    selenium.Click("id=ctl00_cphBody_btnExport");
    selenium.SetSpeed("6000");
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for result complete");
    selenium.IsTextPresent("Specimen Volume Report");
    selenium.IsTextPresent("Display Specimen Detail");

}
```

i do not have control over the filename, and i am wondering whether it is possible for me to either:

1. before downloading the file, explicitly specifying the file name; or
2. grabbing the filename of the last file downloaded?

the filename is something like : `Export23498238974.csv`

Comment: Where do the downloads go? One solution could be give it a certain amount of time to download, scan the downloads directory, grab all the files in it, sort by descending by date created so that the most recently created file is at the top - there is your file. For a better solution, can you explain exactly **how** the filename is generated by the website?

Comment: @Arran thank you very much for your comment. no i do not know how it is downloaded. when you push the export button, the file automatically pushed to the browser.